# How to style an translateX depending on Hammer.js pan?

Tags: javascript, css, hammer.js, gestures

I want to `translateX()` an element when the user pans it using Hammer.js. When the user drags the content left, I want to translate the content left. The same for right.

Current code:

```
var manager = new Hammer.Manager(elem);

var panner = new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, threshold: 0 });

manager.add(panner);

manager.on("panleft", function(e) {
    elem.style.transform = "translateX(" + (e.distance * -1) + "px)";
});

manager.on("panright", function(e) {
    elem.style.transform = "translateX(" + e.distance + "px)";
});
```

It works except if the user pans left then goes *back* right, it glitches and goes negative. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by binding to the `panmove` event and using the `e.deltaX` property:

```
manager.on("panmove", function(e) {
   elem.style.transform = "translateX(" + e.deltaX + "px)";
});
```